# S3 intelligent tiering based on percentage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to maintain the "last" 20% of the objects stored in a specific bucket in a S3 Standard and the rest in Standard-IA?

I might be wrong, but it looks like intelligent tiering allows me to auto-transit objects solely on the last time they were accessed.

Side note - aws documentation is hell on earth.

Answer (score 0):

With intelligent tiering it transits objects based on last accessed only. Idea is that the files you access more frequently are stored as standard tier, so you wouldn't be charged the access fee (as you're charged for infrequent access).
So, if you want to do it based on creation time, you would have to go the standard way, by making lifecycle rules.

There's no way to do this based on number of files in any scenario, only based on time that has passed.

Comment: Thanks, can you think of another way to do this rather than going over all the objects in the bucket and transit them "manually" to the right storage class?

Comment: @eli [Lifecycle rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) as suggested...

Comment: @jogold as I said, I'm looking to keep 20% of my objects in some storage class and the rest in another (I don't remove objects at all). This means that on every insert there should be some balancing of the objects between the storage classes. Unfortunately I haven't seen a way to do this in Lifecycle rules...

Comment: As I said, there's no way to do it based on number of items. If you want automation, only way is to do it with lifecycle rules, where's you'd have to make a best guess as to how much files you'll be adding, and based on that to make them transition to another class. ie. make everything older than 60 days move to another class, for example.Then you can review and modify those rules. Other way could be to write a software or PowerShell script that you would execute